# List unanswered questions in our favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

For users like me, we may be ready to help if we know the answer, but searching for unanswered questions in our area of expertise is tough. I think it could be a good thing if there would be a navigation link for unanswered questions with respect to favorite tags.

Comment: *All* your favorite tags? I just search for a single tag at a time with the normal `[the_tag] answers:0` and click the `Newest` tab.

Comment: (I do wish I could specify `newest` without a click, but I should probably use the API for that maybe.)

Comment: Yes, that could work, but what if I only want some answer questions that are common to VB and WPF only out of all my fav tags, that way I can select questions based on all tags or only the 1 or 2 tags, but questions having all the tags clicked on.